# dependency assemblies, check compatibility

Tags: c#, nuget, nugetgallery

I am converting a project from .net framework to .net core 2.
I need to check if my dependencies are compatible with .net core 2.

how do I check if https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Cells/7.6.0 supports  .net core 2 or .net standard or .net framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in their [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Cells/)

> Platform Independence
>
> You can use Aspose.Cells for .NET to build any type of a 32-bit or
>   64-bit .NET application including ASP.NET, WCF, WinForms, UWP, .NET
>   Standard, .NET Core etc. It is possible to use Aspose.Cells for .NET
>   via COM Interop from ASP, Perl, PHP and Python. You can also use
>   Aspose.Cells for .NET to build applications with Mono.

Updated

On 2018 they have updated their Feature overview [page](https://docs.aspose.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=61543304) indicating they support .net core, so probably must have supported after 18.0 version.

You can ask them by using their customer support [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/)

Comment: That is for Aspose.Cells 18.3.0 though, not 7.6 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Cells/7.6.0

Comment: I tried to install the 7.6.0 package in my own .net core and .net framework application,it got installed.

Comment: yes true. but just because it compiles doesn't mean its runs though. right?